# Call a function in an object and use a property of that object

Tags: javascript

```
let person={
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastname :'dawn',
    birthYear: 1995,
    job:"IT",
    family:['nikita','papa','mom'],
    age:(function(){
        console.log(this);

        return new Date().getFullYear()- this.birthYear;
    })()
};
```

When I am printing the age it is giving me `NaN` as the `this.birthYear` is giving `undefined` as a result.

The question is how can I call the function within the object and use the property of that object only in the function.

Comment: This is an `Object` not a `JSON` string.

Comment: Why not create a class and function inside?

Comment: There is no JSON in your post. JavaScript objects are not JSON.

Comment: `this` in your IIFE is not a reference to the object being built (in fact, when the property initializer for `age` is evaluated, `person` doesn't have a value yet and the `person` variable is inaccessible).

Comment: You can use getters.
See this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616262/5774004